# confluent-kafka Timed out OffsetCommitRequest

Tags: python, consumer, confluent-kafka-python

im using confluent-kafka 1.8.2.
Faced a problem, after N messages the consumer crashes with an error.

GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out OffsetCommitRequest in flight (after 60165ms, timeout #0)

Please help me understand what is wrong and how to fix it.
I use a consumer with these parameters:

```
'enable.auto.commit': True,
'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
'sasl.mechanism': 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
'heartbeat.interval.ms': 3000,
'max.poll.interval.ms': 300000,
'session.timeout.ms': 300000

    try:
    while True:
        msg = consumer.poll()
        if msg is None:
            continue
        if msg.error():
            logger.exception("Consumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
            continue

        logger.info('Received message: %s', message)
```

More logs

Consumer group session timed out (in join-state steady) after 300005 ms without a successful response from the group coordinator (broker 5, last error was Local: Timed out in queue): revoking assignment and rejoining group

GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out 0 in-flight, 0 retry-queued, 1 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests

GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out OffsetCommitRequest in flight (after 60000ms, timeout #0)
GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out OffsetCommitRequest in flight (after 60000ms, timeout #1)
GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out OffsetCommitRequest in flight (after 60000ms, timeout #2)
GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out OffsetCommitRequest in flight (after 60000ms, timeout #3)
GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out OffsetCommitRequest in flight (after 60000ms, timeout #4)
GroupCoordinator/5: Timed out 8301 in-flight, 0 retry-queued, 47924 out-queue, 1 partially-sent requests